# Logical proof of an equivalence

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I want to prove that:
$$x + y.z = (x + y)(x + z)$$
in logic. The right statement equals:
$$(x.x) + (x.y) +(x.z) + (y.z)$$
So if I assume that $x=1$, then the whole statement equals 1, no matter the rest of the statement:
$$1 + y + z + y.z = 1 + A = 1$$
And if I assume that $x=0$ the whole statement equals $y.z$:
$$0 + 0 + 0 + y.z = y.z$$
So it is equivalent to 
$$x + y.z$$
I have proved the equivalence in this way. But I want to know is there any better way with strong mathematical or logical proof for it.
Best Regards

Comment: It's not true that $x+yz = (x+y)(x+z)$. Let $x=1, y=1, z=1$.

Comment: It is a logical equivalence. so $1+1=1$. Plus sign means "or" and Dot sign means "and".

Comment: @PatrickStevens By the `logic` tag I assume that's meant to be a [boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) question. Granted, the OP could/should have spelled that out more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The right statement equals:
>   $$(x.x) + (x.y) +(x.z) + (y.z)$$

Note that $(x.x)=x$ by the [idempotence law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Monotone_laws) and $x+(x.y)=x$ by the absorption one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The key of the solution was absorption law.